# Convert xlsx file to some other type, such that it can be stored in git repo

Tags: spring-boot, apache, xlsx

I have a xlsx file ("File.xlsx").

For a local testing purpose on spring boot project, I have kept it at a certain classpath ("src/main/resources/File.xlsx").

But while pushing to git, it doesn't get uploaded to my git repo because its not supported file format type.

Is there a way to convert this xlsx file(which has multiple sheets and multiple rows per sheet) to some other file type, like json, xml, etc which can be stored and uploaded to git?

Comment: Which git repo are you using? I pushed several `xls` and `xlsx` files to GitHub for testing.

Comment: Ohh, we didn't have access of that actually. Anyways, just changing file type from xlsx to json, and then importing it as Workbook worked for me.
Also json file was uploaded to my git repo.